# while working with network chart, is there any why to color the common node with two different colors.?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, highcharts

[image: this is the one I achieved by using linear gradient]I tried using linear gradient. I can see the two colors. but the thing is it was changing linearly. but what I need is the each color should occupy 50% of node. with out linear change.

My Code:

subchart.point.color = {

```
    linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
    
    stops: [[0, color[0]], 
    
    [0.75, color[1]] 

  ]};
```

can anyone help me on this.?

eg:

I need to change the color immediately when bar is half. i.e. I don't want linear change. eg is similar to my question.
I need to achieve this

[image: I need to achieve this]

[an example link for my question](http://jsfiddle.net/nk7zmxpr/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the color config from the demo that you shared into the networkgraph series:

```
  color: {
    linearGradient: {
      x1: 0,
      x2: 0,
      y1: 0,
      y2: 1
    },
    stops: [
      [0, '#003399'],
      [1, '#ff66AA']
    ]
  }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e5b4kcpq/

Comment: @sebastan the color here it was changing linearly., requirement is like node should be half one color and other half one color